# Display PDF in iframe in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, iframe

I would like to display a pdf in an iframe in one of my Rails projects. My current code is `<iframe src="tmp/data.pdf"></iframe>`, but when I go to this page, I get the error: "No route matches [GET] /Users//development//tmp/data.pdf".

data.pdf is in this location, so I think I'm doing something wrong with my routes file, and maybe I have to route the file to a path appropriately. I've tried playing around with a few things, but haven't had much luck so far. Can anyone provide any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails only exposes the contents of the "public" subfolder to the webbrowser so no code/configuration can be downloaded by any user...

Try putting the file there and it should work.

**UPDATE 1**

Also you need to note, that the "public" part does not have to be included in the URL. So in your case the url would be just "/data.pdf".

Comment: Works for me :)